# Nested modal dialogs and "stopModal"

Tags: macos, cocoa

I'm starting multiple nested modal dialogs using `NSApplication`s `beginModalSessionForWindow`. But if I try to close the topmost session using `stopModal`, **all** nested calls of `runModalSession` return an result not equal to NSRunContinuesResponse.

```
NSModalSession session = [NSApp beginModalSessionForWindow:myWin];
for (;;) {
    // ... during 'runModalSession' 'stopSession' will be called ...
    if ([NSApp runModalSession:session] != NSRunContinuesResponse)
        break; 
}

[NSApp endModalSession:session]
```

Is there a way to stop/close the "topmost" modal session only?

**EDIT:**
  It seems that nested modal Dialogs in OS X (10.11) don't work.
  After switching to another application and back, the dialog order is a mess.

Comment: What is the related window of the nested model sessions? The window, on which the main modal session runs on, or the main modal session's window itself?

Comment: Every modal session has its own window. I have a test function `CreateModal` that: creates a new window, places 2 buttons on it (close, new) and starts a modal session (see the question). The close button triggers `[NSApp stopModal]`, but this closes **all** spawned modal session down to the root (all invocations of `runModalSession`) return a value different to `NSRunContinuesResponse`.

Comment: You say that you use `-stopModal`, but in your code you use `-endModalSession:`?!?

Comment: Don't nest modal dialogs. Or if you really want to nest modal dialogs, call `stopModalWithCode:` instead of `stopModal` and use your own codes.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad Yes, but `endModalSession:` is called _after_ the session was 'stopped' using `stopSession`. `endModalSession` should only end the session passed to it.